# Как добавить данные из формы в БД Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Не уверен ,что этот код вообще юзабельный ,но может можно данные полученные из формы сохранить в бд ?

SiteController

```
public function actionForm()
{
    $form = new BriefForm();

    

    $form->site_name = 'Sa';
    $form->email = 'mail@s.com';
    $form->phone = '09723232';
    $form->user_FIO = 'YAV';
    $form->additional_info= 'vaiasasaco';
    

    $form->save();
   

    if($form->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ){
        $site_name = Html::encode($form->site_name);
        $email = Html::encode($form->email);
    };
    

    return $this->render('form', 
['form' => $form,
'site_name' => $site_name,
'email' => $email,]);




}
```

models/BriefForm

```
<?php
```

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

```
class BriefForm extends  ActiveRecord
{
     public $site_name;
    //  public $operation_kind_new;
    //  public $operation_kind_old;
    
     public $user_FIO;
     public $email;
     public $phone;
     public $additional_info;
     public $domain_name;
    //  public $domain_items = [];
        

    // // ];
    //  public $old_site_defect_items = [];



    public static function tableName(){
        return 'brief_form';
    }
    




    public function rules(){
        return [
            [['site_name','operation_kind','user_FIO','email','phone', 'domain_name'], 'required'],
            ['email' , 'email' , 'message'=> 'Некорректный email' ],

        ];
    }

//     public function bd()
// {

//     // if (!$this->validate()) {
//     //     return null;
//     // }

//     // // $form = new BriefForm();
//     // // $form->site_name = $this->site_name;
//     // // $form->email = $this->email;
//     // // $form->phone = $this->phone;
//     // // $form->domain_name = $this->domain_name;

//     // // return $form->save() ? $form : null;
// }
}
```

?>

views/form

```
    <?php $f= ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
   <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-2">
                  <?=$f->field($form , 'site_name')->label('Название вашего сайта'); ?>
                  <h3 class="text-center">Что нужно сделать</h3>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                      <h3 class="text-center">Создать новый</h3>  
                      <?=$f->field($form , 'domain_name')->label('Домен сайта'); ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                      <h3 class="text-center">Обновить старый</h3>  
                      <?=$f->field($form , 'domain_name')->label('Домен сайта'); ?>
                      
                        <?=$f->field($form , 'additional_info')->label('Дополнительные сведения'); ?>
                  </div>
                  <?=$f->field($form , 'user_FIO')->label('Ваше ФИО'); ?>
                  <?=$f->field($form , 'email')->label('Ваша почта'); ?>
                  <?=$f->field($form , 'phone')->label('Ваш номер телефона'); ?>
                  
                  <?= Html::submitButton('Вперед'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
   <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выглядит ужасно, но для решения вашей проблемы додайте в if приёма post сохранения:

```
if($form->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $form->save()){
    $site_name = Html::encode($form->site_name);
    $email = Html::encode($form->email);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , первый день сегодня изучаю .Сейчас попробую сделать как вы указали